# object import from a different package in Scala in Maven project

Tags: scala, import, package

I need to import an object named JavaCCParser into another object which is in a different package named frontend. But it can not find. I think I write the correct path.

[object in a package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXiCC.jpg)

[import in another package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slPcI.jpg)

I add a dependency in pom.xml in frontend package and then solved it.
[add denpendency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLoQj.jpg)

Comment: You might have another package with exactly the same path as `JavaCCParser` somewhere else, maybe in the `test` directory or somewhere else that is hiding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those don't look like they are in the same `module` (folder with a blue box, contains its own `src` root).

To use `packages` from another `module` would require you to import the `module` as a dependency in the other `module` in the `build.sbt`.

Something like (for a project-wide `build.sbt`):

```scala
lazy val root = project
    .in(file("."))
    .aggregate( neoForJAstFactory, frontend, ... )
    ... // Other config stuff

lazy val neoForJAstFactory = project
    .in(file("neo4j-ast-factory"))
    ... // Other config stuff

lazy val frontend = project
    .in(file("frontend"))
    .dependsOn(neoForJAstFactory)
    ... // Other config stuff
```

Once you add the module as a dependency to the module you wish to use it in, the package should be available for import (it should be in-scope).

Here is the sbt doc: [Multi-Project](https://%20https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Multi-Project.html)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I understand the reason. I sucessed!